# Infinite sum with factorial denominator and exponential numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have this summation:
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 10,000(n-1)\frac{(3/2)^ne^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{n!}   $
The official solution says this this equals:
$10,000(1.5-1)$

How?

Doesn't
$\frac{(3/2)^ne^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{n!}$ reduce to
$e^{\frac{3}{2}} * e^{-\frac{3}{2}} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the constant, we can calculate it directly:$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)\dfrac{(\frac{3}{2})^{n}}{n!}&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n(\frac{3}{2})^{n}}{n!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\frac{3}{2})^{n}}{n!}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\frac{3}{2})^{n}}{(n-1)!}-e^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{3}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\frac{3}{2})^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-e^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{3}{2}e^{\frac{3}{2}}-e^{\frac{3}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{\frac{3}{2}}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$ is correct, but not in case which $(n-1)$ is multiplied in front of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Here, let's take $f(x)=(x-1)e^x$.

$$f^{(0)}(x) = (x-1)e^x$$

$$f^{(1)}(x) = (x-1)e^x + e^x=xe^x$$

$$f^{(2)}(x) = xe^x +e^x=(x+1)e^x$$

$$\vdots$$

$$f^{(n)}(x) = (x+n-1)e^x$$

Therefore, we have

$$f(x) = (x-1)e^x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (x_0+n-1)\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}e^{x_0}$$

Substitute $x_0 = 0$ and $x=\frac{3}{2}$ to get the summation result.